# C double free error after 2nd run of the code

Tags: c, scope, segmentation-fault, function-definition, null-pointer

I'm attempting to develop a library in C & starting with memory management.

Attempting to test my allocation function & free function several times to test for multiple allocations & frees.

However, on the 2nd run of free function I'm getting an double free & crash.

**My simple header:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "xyz_props.h"
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>


Header:

#ifndef XYZ_PROPS_H
#define XYZ_PROPS_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
#include <stdlib.h>
#define DEFAULT_MAX_KEY_SIZE_IN_BYTES       256
#define DEFAULT_MAX_VALUE_SIZE_IN_BYTES     4096
    
/*represents a single linked list node with (key,value) pair*/
typedef struct xyz_config_node
{
    char* key; 
    char* value; 
    struct xyz_config_node* p_next; 
    
} xyz_config_node;

/*represents all properties*/
typedef struct xyz_config_list
{
    xyz_config_node* p_head;
    int KEY_SIZE_IN_BYTES; 
    int VALUE_SIZE_IN_BYTES;  
    
} xyz_config_list;

/*declare variables*/
extern xyz_config_list* p_self;
/*===========================================================================
Function:           xyz_config_alloc      
Description:        allocates heap memory for the wrapper xyz_config_list 
 *                  that contains the head node.
Inputs:             max_key_size in bytes. 
 *                  Input of 0 or greater than 4096 will default to 256 bytes 
 *                  length for the key size. 
 * 
 *                  max_value_size in bytes. 
 *                  Input of 0 or greater than 4096 will default to 4096 bytes 
 *                  length for the value size. 
Outputs:            pointer to xyz_config_list
==========================================================*/
xyz_config_list* xyz_config_alloc(int max_key_size, int max_value_size);

/*===========================================================================
Function:           xyz_config_free
Description:        Frees heap memory allocated to xyz_config_list & the
 *                  linked list within xyz_config_list. 
Inputs:             xyz_config_list** pp_self - pass by reference         
Outputs:            void
References: 
Example call:       xyz_config_free(&props); 
==========================================================*/
void xyz_config_free(xyz_config_list** pp_self);
```

**Implementation C file:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "xyz_props.h"

xyz_config_list* p_self = NULL; 
/*=============================================================================
Private Declarations
==============================================================================*/
xyz_config_list* xyz_config_alloc_helper(int max_key_size, int max_value_size, xyz_config_list** props);

/*=============================================================================
 * Implementations
==============================================================================*/
xyz_config_list* xyz_config_alloc(int max_key_size, int max_value_size) {
   return xyz_config_alloc_helper(max_key_size, max_value_size,&p_self);
}

xyz_config_list* xyz_config_alloc_helper(int max_key_size, int max_value_size, xyz_config_list** props)
{
     if (NULL == *props) {
        *props = (xyz_config_list*) calloc(1, sizeof(xyz_config_list));
        //set max key size
        if (max_key_size > 0 && max_key_size<=4096) {
            (*props)->KEY_SIZE_IN_BYTES = max_key_size;
        } else {
              //defaults to 256 
             (*props)->KEY_SIZE_IN_BYTES = DEFAULT_MAX_KEY_SIZE_IN_BYTES;
             fprintf(stderr,"WARNING xyz_config,xyz_config_alloc_helper(), "
             "max_key_size MUST be 0<max_key_size<=4096.max_key_size is set to "
                     "default 256.\n");
        }
        //set max value size
        if (max_value_size > 0 && max_value_size<=4096) {
            (*props)->VALUE_SIZE_IN_BYTES  = max_value_size;
        } else {
             //defaults to 4096
             (*props)->VALUE_SIZE_IN_BYTES  = DEFAULT_MAX_VALUE_SIZE_IN_BYTES;
             fprintf(stderr,"WARNING xyz_config,xyz_config_alloc_helper(), "
             "max_value_size MUST be 0<max_value_size<=4096.max_value_size is set to "
                     "default 4096.\n");
        }
    }
    return *props;
}

void xyz_config_free(xyz_config_list** pp_self)
{
    if (NULL!=pp_self && NULL!=(*pp_self))
    {
        xyz_config_node* p_current = (*pp_self)->p_head; 
        xyz_config_node* p_next = NULL; 
        //iterate and free the nodes 
        while (NULL!=p_current)
        {
            p_next = p_current->p_next;
            //free child attributes 
            free(p_current->key);
            free(p_current->value);
            //free the node 
            free(p_current);
            p_current = p_next; 
           
        }
        //free the super structure
        if (NULL!=*pp_self)
        {
            free (*pp_self); //ERROR HAPPENS ON 2ND TIME HERE.
            *pp_self = NULL; 
        }

    }
}
```

**Main file:**

```
/*
 * 
 */
void test();
void test2();
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    test();
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

/*single alloc & free*/
void test()
{

    xyz_config_list* props = xyz_config_alloc(128,1600); //defaults to max_key_size=256,max_value_size=4096
    assert(props);

    //finally free all memory 
    xyz_config_free(&props);
    assert(NULL==props);
    
    printf("free\n");
}

/*multiple allocs & frees*/
void test2()
{
    //1-alloc
    xyz_config_list* props = xyz_config_alloc(128,1600); //defaults to max_key_size=256,max_value_size=4096
    assert(props);

    //1-finally free all memory 
    xyz_config_free(&props);
    assert(NULL==props);
    
    //2- alloc 
    props = xyz_config_alloc(128,1600); //defaults to max_key_size=256,max_value_size=4096
    assert(props);

    //2-finally free all memory 
    xyz_config_free(&props); //CRASH in 2nd free function. Output: RUN FINISHED; Segmentation fault; core dumped; 
    assert(NULL==props);
    
    printf("free\n");
}
```

The debugger memory & variables watch at the 1st run:

[image]

The debugger memory & variables watch at the 2nd run where there is a problem:

[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you have the global `p_self` variable at all? I think it would be much easier to debug if you got rid of that.

Comment: @EdmCoff, well it's just where the variable lives, it's just pointer to the struct that contains both other data structures & other relevant data. Without OOP it would be difficult to do otherwise, regardless its not directly related to double free. What pattern would you suggest?

Comment: @EdmCoff, Ok i removed the `extern` keyword. Its was a relic from early version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the problem is relative to declaring the variable `p_self` in the file scope

```
xyz_config_list* p_self = NULL;
```

This variable is used in the function `xyz_config_alloc_helper`. The memory is allocated only in case when the file scope variable `p_self` is  equal to `NULL`.

```
xyz_config_list* xyz_config_alloc(int max_key_size, int max_value_size) {
   return xyz_config_alloc_helper(max_key_size, max_value_size,&p_self);
                                                               ^^^^^^^
}
```

and (within the function `xyz_config_alloc_helper`)

```
 if (NULL == *props) {
    *props = (xyz_config_list*) calloc(1, sizeof(xyz_config_list));
```

However in the function `xyz_config_free` the variable is not set to `NULL` because the function deals with the local variable declared in functions test and test2 as for example

```
xyz_config_list* props = xyz_config_alloc(128,1600); //defaults to max_key_size=256,max_value_size=4096
assert(props);

//1-finally free all memory 
xyz_config_free(&props);
```

And here the code snippet from the function where it sets to `NULL` the local pointer passed tp the function by reference

```
    if (NULL!=*pp_self)
    {
        free (*pp_self); //ERROR HAPPENS ON 2ND TIME HERE.
        *pp_self = NULL; 
    }
```

That is *pp_self is not the same object as the object in the file scope `p_self`.

So when the function `xyz_config_free` is called the second time it tries to free already freed memory because before the second time the new memory was not allocated due to the fact that the file scope variable was not set to NULL in the previous call of the function `xyz_config_free`

The lessons from this bug is try to avoid to define functions that depend on file scope variables.

Comment: Lesson learned. However I how would I avoid passing the `p_self` on every call if I dont declare it globally???

Comment: @cyber101 What does prevent to pass local pointers by reference to the function xyz_config_alloc? Otherwise you need to set the file scope variable to NULL in the function that frees the allocated memory

Comment: True, however exposing functions that require reference to that structure looks ugly for the end user. I just wanted something like this add(key,value) rather than add(key,value,&pp_self) in the header.

Comment: @cyber101 Unfortunately I cam say nothing because I do not know the design ideas of the program. I have pointed the reason of the run-time error.